# Implement slice_shift_char using the std library

Tags: rust

I'd like to use the `&str` method `slice_shift_char`, but it is marked as unstable in the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.slice_shift_char):

> Unstable: awaiting conventions about shifting and slices and may not
>   be warranted with the existence of the chars and/or char_indices
>   iterators

What would be a good way to implement this method, with Rust's current std library? So far I have:

```
fn slice_shift_char(s: &str) -> Option<(char, &str)> {
    let mut ixs = s.char_indices();
    let next = ixs.next();
    match next {
        Some((next_pos, ch)) => {
            let rest = unsafe {
                s.slice_unchecked(next_pos, s.len())
            };
            Some((ch, rest))
        },
        None => None
    }
}
```

I'd like to avoid the call to `slice_unchecked`. I'm using Rust 1.1.

Comment: `s.slice_unchecked(a, b)` == `&s[a..b]` but without the bounds checking. (And `&s[a..s.len()]` is `&s[a..]`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can look at the source code, and you'll get https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libcollections/str.rs#L776-L778 and https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libcore/str/mod.rs#L1531-L1539 . The second:

```
fn slice_shift_char(&self) -> Option<(char, &str)> {
    if self.is_empty() {
        None
    } else {
        let ch = self.char_at(0);
        let next_s = unsafe { self.slice_unchecked(ch.len_utf8(), self.len()) };
        Some((ch, next_s))
    }
}
```

If you don't want the unsafe, you can just use a normal slice:

```
fn slice_shift_char(&self) -> Option<(char, &str)> {
    if self.is_empty() {
        None
    } else {
        let ch = self.char_at(0);
        let len = self.len();
        let next_s = &self[ch.len_utf8().. len];
        Some((ch, next_s))
    }
}
```

Comment: The implementation relies on `slice_unchecked` as well. It seems my only choice is between an unstable function and or an unsafe call.

Comment: You can use string slicing if you don't want the unsafe: &s[next_pos..s.len()]

Comment: Still learning Rust - I did not know you can slice strings. I assume this is done at the byte level (and not char). Could you edit your answer to use string slicing?

Comment: yup, it's bytes, and sure

Answer (score 5):

The unstable `slice_shift_char` function has been deprecated since Rust 1.9.0 and removed completely in Rust 1.11.0.

As of Rust 1.4.0, the [recommended approach](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27754#issuecomment-195478632) of implementing this is:

1. Use [`.chars()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.chars) to get an iterator of the `char` content
2. Iterate on this iterator once to get the first character.
3. Call [`.as_str()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Chars.html#method.as_str) on that iterator to recover the remaining uniterated string.

```
fn slice_shift_char(a: &str) -> Option<(char, &str)> {
    let mut chars = a.chars();
    chars.next().map(|c| (c, chars.as_str()))
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(slice_shift_char("hello"), Some(('h', "ello")));
    assert_eq!(slice_shift_char("ĺḿńóṕ"), Some(('ĺ', "ḿńóṕ")));
    assert_eq!(slice_shift_char(""), None);
}
```